# How to monitor changes in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I use **Angular** + **TypeScript**.

My project has a few components with views. I want to add a view helper classes and added them to my project.

But it seems I manually have to run `npm run build` in order to compile them, otherwise Angular can't find the corresponding `*.js` files.

Is there any way how to automatically build/monitor changes/additions of TypeScript files?

Answer (score 3):

the TypeScript compiler (tc) has a --watch parameter that will watch your folder for changes and recompile the affected files.

Comment: I feel so stupid! Thank you! Accepted once I can from SO

Comment: you probably don't need to call that directly, but as a part of a larger build task, i.e. `npm start dev` or similar